# How to make an array for each individual row of integers in a file

Tags: java, arrays, file

Here is the file:

```
18  64  94  54  34  44
40  26  26  92  96  34
56  24  40  92  70  58
92  72  12  46  46  56
50  28  2  64  12  58
98  28  40  88  86  20
46  56  100  60  52  12
82  70  98  18  50  30
58  36  98  4  74  76
76  28  72  74  74  60
```

Here is my code so far:

```
int[] ND1Row1 = new int[6];
for (int column = 0; column < 6; column++) {
    if (fileScan.hasNextInt()) {
        ND1Row1[column] = fileScan.nextInt();
    }
}
```

I just want to be able to have one array for each row in my file.

Answer (score 0):

If its a file you can use readline to read each line and StringTokenizer to get the integer values from the line read.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to declare each array individually and fill them using nested for loops therefore you would have to know the amount of lines in the file.
Alternatively you could count the number of line then create a 2 dimensional array.

Answer (score 0):

With the code you pass the first Line into one array
you can use a for(before) the (**if(fileScan.hasNextLine())**) based on how many
arrays you want to create.
Everytime you have to create a new array.I think you can find how.

```
    Scanner fileScan;
    try {
         fileScan = new Scanner(new File("file destination"));


        for(......)
         if(fileScan.hasNextLine()){
             int[] ND1Row1 = new int[6]; //create the first array

            for(int column=0; column<6; column++)
                ND1Row1[column] = Integer.parseInt(fileScan.next());

         }//end of  if(fileScan.hasNextLine())

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e){e.printStackTrace();}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int[][] ND1Row1 = new int[10][6];
for(int column = 0; column < 6; column++){
   for(int i= 0; i < 10; column++){
      if(fileScan.hasNextInt()){
            ND1Row1[i][column] = fileScan.nextInt();
      }
   }
}
```